# How does MATLAB interpolate pixels using bicubic?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bicubic

I don't know that MATLAB interpolates pixels using bicubic method.

The interpolated pixels by bicubic in MATLAB are different from interpolated pixels by bicubic which is implemented by R. G. Keys [1].

Could you explan how to interpolate pixels by using bicubic method in MATLAB not bicubic by [1].
Then, explain why those are different.

e.g.

MATLAB:

```
imresize([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 8], 'bicubic')

ans = 0.9297 1.1797 1.7266 2.2500 2.7500 3.2734 3.8203 4.0703
```

[1]:

```
[1.0000 1.4375 2.0000 2.50000 3.0000 3.5625 4.0000 4.0625]
```

pixels are obtained by interpolating `[1 2 3 4]` pixels using bicubic method in [1].

Thanks.

[1] Cubic Convolution Interpolation for Digital Image Processing”, IEEE Trans on ASSP, vol ASSP-29, No. 6, Dec 1981

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples are interpolating different points. Your reference data [1] seems to calculate points for `1:.5:4.5` while MATLAB uses `0.75:0.5:4.25` for symmetry reasons.